# Convert blob url to streamable HTML video(tag) url

Tags: javascript, html, video, blob

I have this blob url from my server containing part of a video

> blob:https%3A//cnd.thisisparta.be/725172f6-7ca4-479e-9f2a-bbbe0c246d4d

Is there any possible way to stream this in the browser(client-side) without having to download it first?

I tried this

```
<video src="blob:https%3A//cnd.thisisparta.be/725172f6-7ca4-479e-9f2a-bbbe0c246d4d" controls></video>
```

But this just stays disabled.

Comment: I don't know much about blob URLs, but that doesn't look like a valid blob URL according to the spec - http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#url

Comment: @Dan is right, simply adding `blob:` in front of an HTTP(S) URL doesn’t make this a blob.

Comment: this is what it returns => RIFFÎÃvAVI LISTr"��hdrlavih8���@œ������������´� .......

Comment: Avi files are not playable in the video tag. Only ogg, MP4, and webm.